# /setblock with command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to `/setblock` to a player position in 1.15+?
I already tried watching some Youtube videos, but they were all like 5 years old, so is there a way to do so in newer versions of Minecraft?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the block at the player's feet,

```
/execute at @p run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ [block] replace
```

Comment: Thx, helped a lot!